# why does $\mathbf{Q}$ lie dense in $\mathbf{R}$ and $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ lie dense in $\mathbf{C}$

Tags: general-topology

Why is $\mathbf{Q}$ dense in $\mathbf{R}$?

Does this imply that (Edit: the field of algebraic numbers) $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ is dense in $\mathbf{C}$?

For the first question, I guess one has to show that for every $x$ in $\mathbf{R}$ and every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a rational number $q$ such that $\vert x- q \vert < \epsilon$. Does the proof of this rely upon methods from Diophantine Approximation or is it easier than this?

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb Q}\supset\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The density of the rational numbers inside the real numbers follows from the very definition of real numbers as (classes of equivalence of) [Cauchy sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) of rational numbers. By definition, every real number is the limit of some sequence of rational numbers.

As for your second question: which is the meaning of your $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$?

Added:  If $\overline{\mathbb Q}\supset\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$, you can just prove density separately in the real and imaginary axes

Comment: I guess $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ should mean the algebraic closure of $\mathbf{Q}$

Comment: @AgustiRoig:  I put the Added into your answer instead of mine by accident.  Feel free to delete it if you want.

Comment: Don't worry, Ross.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my comment, the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb C$ is dense because it contains $\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$, which, as others explained, is dense.

Answer (score 3):

For the first, just take a rational with large enough denominator ($2/\epsilon$ will work)

For the second, what do you mean by $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$?  If it is the closure of $\mathbf{Q}$, that is $\mathbf{R}$, but you don't get very close to $i$ with any real numbers.  Maybe you want $\mathbf{Q}\times\mathbf{Q}$?

Added:  If $\overline{\mathbb Q}\supset\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$, you can just prove density separately in the real and imaginary axes

Answer (score 1):

If q is a rational number, then the sequence {q,q,..,q,...,q} converges to q.

If $q$ is irrational, then, by the LUB property, it has a (non-periodic) decimal

expansion $a.q_oq_1...q_n.....$ for $a, q_0,q_1,...,q_n,... $integers  . Then the sequence : {a,$a+\frac {q_0}{10}, a+\frac{q_0}{10}+\frac{q_1}{10^2},......., a+\frac{q_0}{10}+.......+\frac{q_n}{10^{n+1}},....$ converges to q.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $\mathbb R$ is defined as some complete ordered field, then first prove the archimedean property, so that there is no positive number $< 1/n$ for all natural numbers $n$, and then the "rational with large enough denominator" trick will work.